# How to allow users login with both registered account and facebook account?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, omniauth

I used devise to allow users register and login within the site. I also used omniauth-facebook to allow users login with their facebook accounts. However, people who registered first with the same email as their facebook-email cannot login with their facebook account.I want to use both facebook login and site registration.

This is my user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                         )
    end
    user
  end
end
```

And omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to use both facebook login as well as devise (email/pass) or just one of them?. I can answer your question based on that - thanks

Comment: @matrixtheone I want to use both facebook login and devise registration. thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this the following way:

1. Create another model called Authorization with the attributes:

   ```
   provider:string, uid:string, user_id:integer
   ```
2. Now User would be associated with Authorization as follows:

   ```
   class User
     has_many :authorizations
     ...
   end
   ```
3. Whenever a facebook login occurs, check with the authorizations model to see if a record is present. If not create it and link it to the user model (by searching by email id).
4. Get the proper user object and login with it.

Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-use-omniauth-to-authenticate-your-users/

Comment: thanks, i have solved the problem based on your solution. GREAT HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I asked the question and just found ways out based on matrixtheone's anwser (really great help) and this blog.
http://www.orhancanceylan.com/rails-twitter-and-facebook-authentications-with-omniauth-and-devise/

Here is the code. If there is something wrong, please figure it out

```
def facebook
  omni = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omni['provider'],omni['uid'])

  if authentication
    flash[:notice] = "Logged in Successfully"
    sign_in_and_redirect User.find(authentication.user_id)
  elsif user = User.find_by(email: omni['extra']['raw_info'].email)
    user.authentications.create!(provider:omni['provider'], 
                        uid:omni['uid'])
    flash[:notice] = "Authentication for registered user is successful"
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  else
    user = User.new
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.email = omni['extra']['raw_info'].email
    user.authentications.build(provider:omni['provider'], 
                        uid:omni['uid'])
    if user.save
      flash[:notice] = "Logged in."
      sign_in_and_redirect User.find(user.id)
    else
      session[:omniauth] = omni.except('extra')
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a security issue with this kind of login logic. You can steel user accounts that way!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom validation for the email field in user model like

```
email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, :presence =>{:message => "An email address must be entered."},
                    :format => { :with => email_regex , :message => "The email address is not valid." },
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false,  :message => "The email address is already used."}
```

Comment: any time when you want's to save user record it will validate in the email already exists in the database or not.